# SSRS adding hyperlink with field URL

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am trying to add hyperlink with url field into textbox.

> "can be accessed at " + <a href=First(Fields!url.Value,"dsScheduleA")>First(Fields!url.Value,
> "dsScheduleA");/a>

this one is for expression for value. is this working fine?

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a working hyperlink using HTML - you must use the ACTION property of the textbox.

For the text box, your text expression would be

```
="can be accessed at " & Fields!url.Value,"dsScheduleA")
```

Then go to the Action property and select Go to URL and select the URL field.

[image]

Comment: When I tried this, the hyperlink works fine, but it doesn't change color (blue with the line)

Comment: @JinHuh You have to do that manually, change the color to blue and underline it.